# EEHarbor Transcribe 1.6 and EE 2.8 - error

Tags: ee2-upgrades, transcribe, eeharbor

We're getting the following error when we upgrade to 2.8 and 1.6 transcribe:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING or '(' in /httpdocs/system/expressionengine/third_party/transcribe/mod.transcribe.php on line 9
```

Think it must be due to them require PHP 5.3+ but we're running 5.2.10, anyone able to recommend a fix for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out our server didn't have the required PHP version for 1.6 of transcribe